# how to use Object.assign with literals on a reducer with defined returning flow type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, flow-js

I'm writing a reducer that will be used along with `React.useReducer` hook. Flow is used, but the reducer is suffering from a flow error because `Object.assign({}, state ...` has `{}` as an object literal that is incompatible with `SearchLocationStateType`.
The only solution I've found is listing all the properties on each object literal, which is not the right way.

How could I fix this?

```
type SearchLocationStateType = {
    textAreaFocused: boolean,
    promptsShown: boolean,
};

export const ACTIONS = Object.freeze({
    FOCUS_SEARCH_TEXT: 'FOCUS-SEARCH-TEXT',
    BLUR_SEARCH_TEXT: 'BLUR-SEARCH-TEXT',
});

type ActionType = {
    type: $Values<typeof ACTIONS>,
};

const reducer = (state: SearchLocationStateType, action: ActionType): SearchLocationStateType => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTIONS.FOCUS_SEARCH_TEXT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {textAreaFocused: true});
        case ACTIONS.BLUR_SEARCH_TEXT:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {textAreaFocused: false});
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't using type casting  sufficient like this:  return Object.assign({}, state, {textAreaFocused: true}) as SearchLocationStateType ;

Comment: maybe  you mean `return (Object.assign({}, state, { textAreaFocused: true }): SearchLocationStateType);` but that raises the same problem, just within parenthesis

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason why you prefer Object.assign instead of object destructring?

Comment: because it's too long since I last touched ES that I didn't figure it out. Destructuring makes it! Can you write it as an answer so as to select it as the solution? Thanks

Comment: As an alternative, you could always use property spread syntax: `return { ...state, textAreaFocused: true };`